# Is there a way to bring all definitions in a C++ struct/class into scope without deriving from it?

Tags: c++

Musing on a Sunday...

Deriving from a class brings all names from the base class into the scope of the derived class. However, it also adds the base class non-static data members to every instance of the derived class.

Is there a way to achieve the former without the latter? I'm asking in the interest of concise notation.

Obviously, when the base class doesn't have any data members, I get what I want. There are quite a few empty classes or class templates in the standard library defined to do just that - inject names summarily into a class scope through inheritance. There's even the empty base class optimization to make this as cheap as possible.

But if I wanted to do the same with a non-empty base class, I would be tempted to employ something like:

```cpp
struct Bar {
    using struct Foo;
};
```

But, alas, that's not supported by C++. My question is, is there another way to achieve the same which I overlooked?

To provide a more complete example:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    enum { some_constant=42 };

    // data members follow here ...
};

struct Bar {
    using class Foo;   // this doesn't compile

    int f();
};

int Bar::f() {
    return some_constant;   // I want to use the constant directly, without Foo::
}
```

One clumsy way could be to split the definitions in Foo into two classes, one with the constants (which would be an empty class I could derive from without penalty) and the other with the data members, but that looks rather like an inelegant hack to me.

If there isn't a clean way to achieve this, maybe someone can provide a rationale for why it doesn't exist, or perhaps shouldn't exist.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to arrive at a maximally concise notation, particularly when there are many constants defined in the class.

Comment: It doesn't exist because no one has made a proposal defining it, and shepherded it though the standardization process. How exactly would you augment the name lookup rules to accommodate this facility? Should it find just the enum values? What about typedefs? Static data members and member functions? Non-static ones? Should it look into base classes of the class nominated by the `using class` directive? Into classes **that** class nominates with `using class`? What should happen if a name exists in the proper base class as well as the one nominated by `using class`?

Comment: For the moment, I was assuming that it would work just like derivation, except that the non-static data members aren't added to the client class. Would there be any problem with that? Of course, one could inherit the definitions as private, protected or public, depending on where the `using class Foo;` line is placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Deriving from a class brings all names from the base class into the scope of the derived class.

Let me stop you there. Yes, it is true that inheriting from a base class causes the (non-`private`) names in the base class to be accessible from the derived class definition. However, that's not *why* you inherit from a base class; that's merely the mechanism by which inheritance achieves its goal.

To publicly inherit from a base class is to make a statement about the relationship between the derived and base classes. You're saying that every instance of the derived class should behave like the base class in virtually all ways. Even `virtual` function overriding still carries with it the expectation that the derived class implementations of these methods are conceptually doing the same job, just in a way appropriate for that derived class.

This is true even of mixin-style base classes, where the base class is used to define common functionality that is imported into a particular derived class. In such interfaces, there is little expectation of a user explicitly talking to base class definitions. But this provision of common functionality is ultimately still based on the semantic idea of a derived class *being* a base class. And that's very important for many of them to do their job.

Consider what is probably the most prominent mixin in the C++ standard library: `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>`. It has non-static data members, without which it couldn't actually provide the functionality it does (well, it could, but you would have to provide some interface in your derived class to store them, so it may as well do it).

This is true of private inheritance, though there is some modification. While to the outside world, the derived class is just a derived class, to the class definition itself, it still remains a base class. It remains wholly a base class, along with all the baggage that comes along with it.

Do not mistake the mechanism for the meaning. Mechanisms are important; don't get me wrong. But those mechanisms exist to facilitate *meaning*.

Having a class contain everything of some other class *except* the non-static data members is, semantically, nonsense. It doesn't mean anything about the relationship between the types. And you've essentially admitted that the main reason you want this is so that you don't have to scope-qualify the names defined in the "base" class.

This is a mechanical reason, not a semantic one. You shouldn't employ a semantic tool like inheritance to escape the mechanical consequences of how you have chosen to design your types.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it still doesn't solve my problem. I may have been trying to misuse inheritance, but only because I couldn't see a better way to give me what I want. I'm not hooked to it, if there is indeed a better way I'm all for it. But so far all such alternatives involve splitting definitions into two parts, and that also puts them physically apart in the source, even though they can of course live in the same file. But if this has to be, it shall be. Not optimal, but I can live with it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

In reference to your specific example you could make the constants you want to access static, which will allow you to access them from the second class by fully qualifying with the "base" class

Comment: For a motivating example, consider struct Foo defining the register set of a hardware peripheral in a microcontroller, and struct Bar would be the definition of a device driver for that peripheral. Foo would never get instantiated, because the register set exists in hardware. Bar, however, would get instantiated, and need the definitions in Foo.

Comment: I have to admit, your use case is beyond my own experience and I'm struggling to picture what that looks like in code: hope you don't mind me asking some questions. In your context what are the functions you want to inherit, and the data you don't want to inherit? I guess the ultimate question I am driving at is: why can't the functions you need in your "sub" class be implemented in a separate class that both derive from? Or rather, what is it you find clumsy/hacky about it?

Comment: It is predominantly constants I want to inherit, not functions. In the motivating example, this would be bitmasks for register bits and bitfields, and definitions for the values to put into them. The vast majority of that can be defined as enum values. The splitting into two classes is indeed the solution that comes nearest to what I need, but it feels odd that I have to split at all, since the constants pertain closely to the registers, so my feeling is that the definitions belong together.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. In that case then I think it probably does make sense to make the constants static, then you can access them without instantiating the class. Do you think that is a better fit? I'll update my answer to remove the bit about SRP: I agree it does make sense to keep the constants and functions together in this case so I was off the mark with this

Comment: @sh-: It seems to me that this problem has nothing to do with any semantic meaning. That is, inheritance actually means something; it expresses a relationship between two types. What you're trying to do is just make syntax a bit more convenient for you, to remove qualifiers that you feel are unnecessary. That's what *namespaces* are for, to represent logical grouping of multiple definitions.

Comment: @castro: I know I can access them that way, but if I derive from the class in order to bring the constants into scope, the non-statics are going to be included in my derived class, which I do want to instantiate. So what you're proposing doesn't help.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: It isn't inheritance in "meaning", in this I agree with you. But using derivation to bring identifiers into scope is a widespread pattern that is also used in the standard library (`std::iterator` has done that for a very long time). If it was bad style, that would make a lot of current practice questionable. But I agree, it could be done with a namespace instead of a split-off struct, but either way I would need to separate things into two parts rather than putting definitions together that relate to each other.

Comment: @sh-: "*If it was bad style, that would make a lot of current practice questionable.*" `std::iterator` is deprecated, and for good reason. And other mixin-type mechanisms still abide by the semantics of inheritance: the derived class "is-a" base class. "*I would need to separate things into two parts rather than putting definitions together that relate to each other.*" I contest whether it is reasonable for these things to be part of the same class to begin with. Unless you're trying to hide an enumerator behind private access, there's no reason to put one in a class.

Comment: I once was taught that "is-a" gets modeled by public inheritance, but there are other types of inheritance which may convey other kinds of meaning regarding the relationship. In particular, private derivation typically does NOT imply an "is-a" relationship. It would often be better regarded as a "implemented-in-terms-of" or "implemented-with-the-help-of" relationship. In my case, private inheritance would be just fine. But do tell, is this an outdated view of inheritance, and why?

Comment: @sh- I assumed your constants were publicly accessible and could therefore be accessed without the need for inheritance. If they are protected/private, why not just make your second class a friend of the former?

Comment: @castro: Making the second class a friend doesn't give me the concise style I'm after; I would still need to use the class name with the scope resolution operator on every use. It doesn't inject the enum constants into the scope of my class.

Comment: @Nico Bolas: Before I forget: I didn't get why you think the definitions don't belong together to begin with. If I am defining a struct representing the register set of a piece of hardware, and the constants pertain to the bits in those regsiters, why do they not belong together? I would claim the opposite: They are closely related and should be defined together.

Comment: @sh-: "*If I am defining a struct representing the register set of a piece of hardware, and the constants pertain to the bits in those regsiters, why do they not belong together?*" They do belong together. I don't understand why "together" to you means "in that class". Post C++11, there's basically no good reason to put enums in a class unless you want to hide the enumeration by making it private. What do you gain by putting them in the same class that could not be gained by putting them in the same *header*?

Comment: I was assuming that "togetherness" is something that should be reflected in the source. I.e. via proximity of location in the source text. In case of good old "C" code, you could frequently see people defining macros in the middle of a struct definition to make clear that the macro is to be used together with the struct member just defined. Macros are yucky, of course. That's what the C folks did, and I like the intent but not the mechanism. I try to find a "clean" C++ solution that's close in spirit to that C practice.

Comment: @sh-: You can do that if you like, but you also must accept the *price* of scoping such definitions. Namely... if you want to access such definitions, you have to explicitly scope those names. Also, scoping a name tends to imply a very tight coupling between the name being defined and the scope it is defined within. Broadly speaking, if an enumeration can *ever* be meaningfully used without the class it is defined within, then it shouldn't be defined within it. This is why `value_type` is a member of iterator classes; that name is fundamentally bound to that type.

Comment: I think the tight coupling is definitely there. Using constants that relate to a specific bit or bitfield in a specific register tend to only make sense in code that accesses this very register. In such code, you don't want to have to write lots of scope resolution boilerplate, because it is clear from the context which names are meant. Hence my wish for conciseness.